# Oracle designer - generate scripts for multiple table/views at same time

Tags: oracle, toad

I have made changes in multiple tables in Toad and I am now required to generate the script for a release in Oracle Designer.
So I made the changes in Oracle Designer and need to generate the script - is there any way I can do this for multiple tables/views at the same time or will I end up with lots of generated script??
Thanks in advance

Comment: Using TOAD you can multiple select the tables, then click the right button of the mouse and select CREATE SCRIPT.  It is not enough clear if you need to realize SYNCHRONIZATION SCRIPTS (for example ALTER TABLE for adding new columns), or if you are authorized to drop all the tables and re-create them with the new scripts.  You've not specified if these changes involve also data changes, in example for master data tables.

Comment: With the TOAD functionality DATABASE / COMPARE / SCHEMA you can realize synchronization scripts, if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select all the tables and views you want to have generated. Start the generation by pressing the button in the toolbar. The first page of the dialog shows all the objects you have selected.

You will get a file per table/view and 1 file with *.sql extension to call all the single files.